# So you're saying that multiple close votes from users can total up to one?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, grammar, plurals

I know this is an extremely small grammar problem, and that it is rather pointless to fix it, but when a question has 4 close votes and you hover your mouse over the "close" button for about half a second it says:

> You voted to close as [Reason]. 1 more vote from **other users** is needed to close this question.

...but it should say:

> You voted to close as [Reason]. 1 more vote from **another user** is needed to close this question.

Sometimes I edit a huge truckload of posts just to fix the grammar screw-ups, so don't be surprised if I post this sort of thing again.

Comment: Ah, good ol pluralisation bugs

Comment: I'm just pointing out a tiny little oopsie and yet I get 60 reputation for it... :0