# Pluralization issue on "Resolve 1 issues before posting": "issues" should be "issue"

Tags: bug, error-message, plurals

Typo on "Resolve 1 issues before posting": *issues* should be *issue*.

[image]

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog I appreciate your edit (definitely a better title,thanks!) but can you please keep the original picture when resizing, so that we don't lose in image quality? Thanks!

Comment: I've linked the original image behind the resized one. By the way, the resize was done using the built-in image resizer, so any issues with lost quality should be reported here.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Thanks, I think `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGFW8.png" width="350" />` is preferable, so that the HD image is shown.

Comment: I actually used to use that in the past, but some others complained to me that that doesn't show properly on mobile devices.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog interesting. I'm on mobile, works great! Using low quality images with blurry texts doesn't look professional and isn't friendly to the eyes

Comment: related: [Please fix the pluralization in “earned this badge 1 times.”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331757)  (resolved) and [So you're saying that multiple close votes from users can total up to one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348378) (unresolved)

Comment: Don't mention Jeff Atwood.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q why would I?